# Big Query SQL, convert row data to columns without specific column headers

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working with a data table that tracks objects entering and leaving a scope. The objects have an id and a value of 1 when they enter and null when they leave, each event is timestamped.

I am trying to track the number of objects in the scope over time.

For example I have:

| Timestamp | Object ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | obj1 | 1 |
| 2 | obj2 | 1 |
| 3 | obj2 | NULL |
| 3 | obj3 | 1 |
| 5 | obj4 | 1 |
| 7 | obj2 | 1 |
| 7 | obj3 | NULL |
| 8 | obj3 | 1 |

I would want to transform it into:

| Timestamp | obj1 | obj2 | obj3 | obj4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | 1 | NULL |
| 5 | 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

My understanding of the Pivot command is that I must specify constant column headers, but for this task the object ids are variable.

I can potential use another query to find all the distinct object ids and insert this into the current query, but would first like to know if there is a better approach.

Is Pivot the correct approach or is there another that would be better suited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating some sample data:

```sql
with tbl as (select
cast(x/3 as int64)  as time,
 "OBJ"||cast(rand()*10 as int64) as obj,
rand() as value
from unnest(generate_array(1,30)) x
)

Select * from tbl
```

First we query all the entries of the column `obj` and save this array as `list`.

Then `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` does the pivot query.

```sql
declare list string;

set list = (
SELECT string_agg(distinct obj,'","')  FROM dataset.tbl
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
" Select * from dataset.tbl"
|| '''pivot( sum(value) for obj in ("''' || list || '''" )) '''
```